# How many CP/M-86 copies were sold?

Tags: operating-system, cp-m

Approximately how many CP/M-86 copies or licenses did Digital Research sell across the product life of the operating system? Are there any data or estimates?

I know the success of MS-DOS didn't leave CP/M-86 much market share, but it would be interesting to have some figures.

Comment: A datapoint: In Denmark the Danish computer vendor Regnecentralen used first CP/M-80 and then on their public school computers CCP/M-86 (ending with Concurrent DOS).   They had four virtual consoles similar to what Linux provide today.  Very nice machines.  I do not know the sales numbers.

Comment: I’m guessing there might be some ambiguity as to the product life of C/PM-86 given how it morphed through Concurrent DOS into DOS Plus, which begat DR DOS. Presumably the cut-off would be between those final two, i.e. up to the point that the CP/M interface was removed?

Comment: It's a good point but I'm not sure such detailed data are available, so for the time being it may be better not to constrain the product life.

Comment: The DEC Rainbow came with a version of CPM that could run CPM-86 code and also CPM-80 code.  The name was something like CPM-80/86.